# OneLogin OIDC grant request is invalid

Tags: onelogin, openid-connect

I have a Java application with an Angular 4 front end and I'm trying to implement Open ID Connect authorization with OneLogin.  I have the app configured in OneLogin with a redirect URL that is an API endpoint to collect the code generated by OneLogin.  Steps 1 - 3 are working as described in the OneLogin documentation, but step 4 fails every time and I cannot figure out why.

*Step 1*: the user attempts to start a session with your client app and is redirected to the OpenID Provider (OneLogin), passing in the client ID, which is unique for that application. - **This works, the user is redirected to a login page hosted by OneLogin.**

*Step 2*: the OpenID Provider authenticates and authorizes the user for a particular application instance. - **This works**

*Step 3*: a one-time-use code is passed back to the web server using a predefined Redirect URI. - **The URI is an API endpoint on the server and it does successfully get the code from OneLogin**

*Step 4*: the web server passes the code, client ID, and client secret to the OpenID Provider’s token endpoint, and the OpenID Provider validates the code and returns a one-hour access token. - **This is where it falls apart for me.**

The only response I get back is "grant request is invalid".  The HTTP POST that I am constructing for this step looks like this:

```
curl -XPOST "https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/token"
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
-d "grant_type=authorization_code
&code=<code returned in step 3>
&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
&client_id=<My OIDC Client ID>
&client_secret=<My OIDC Client Secret>"
```

And the response every time is:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "grant request is invalid"
}
```

I'm at a complete loss as to what to try next.

Comment: Did you ever manage to solve that? 3 years later, I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code-grant , you need to base64 encode the clientid & secret and include it in an auth header.

```
curl -XPOST "https://<region>.onelogin.com/oidc/token" \
-H "Authorization: Basic <base64 encoded client_id:client_secret>" \
-H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" \
-d "grant_type=authorization_code&code=<authorization code>&redirect_uri=<registered redirect uri>"
```

Comment: no, the OP provides the credentials as part of the body, which should be sufficient.

Comment: I think John is correct here. Follow the documentation he has shared. You need to Base64 Encode Client ID and Secret. Also check what is the Token Endpoint Authentication method you have set in your OneLogin OIDC App. It should be visible under first column

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're not including `code_verifier` in your POST request, this may be the issue. It should be the string that was used to create `code_challenge` for the previous step using SHA-256 hash algorithm.

Also, I just had the same error when I used the 1st google result for an online SHA-256 hash generator. When I instead used [this one](https://example-app.com/pkce), I got the token from the server successfully